# How to uninstall TrueCrypt?

Tags: macos, truecrypt

How to uninstall TrueCrypt 7.1a from my Mac cleanly? The [instruction on TrueCrypt website](http://www.truecrypt.org/docs/uninstalling-truecrypt) is Windows-only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `TrueCrypt` installer is an `mpkg` file that contains multiple `pkg` files within it. You can right click the installer in `Finder`, open package contents and see the `pkg` files. Essentially, it installs MacFUSE and the TrueCrypt application. If you examine the `TrueCrypt` `mpkg` file with a tool like [Pacifist](http://www.charlessoft.com/), you'd see the list of files it installs and the locations.

`TrueCrypt` does not come with an uninstaller on OS X. But there are at least two ways to *attempt* to uninstall it completely:

- According to help on the `TrueCrypt` forum, [uninstalling it is a matter of removing MacFuse and the TrueCrypt app](http://forums.truecrypt.org/viewtopic.php?p=67359#67359) (you need to have an account on that forum to see this post):

  > sudo /Library/Filesystems/fusefs.fs/Support/uninstall-macfuse-core.sh
  >   sudo rm -rf /Applications/TrueCrypt.app

  OR
- Try [UninstallPKG](http://www.corecode.at/uninstallpkg/index.html) to uninstall any application installed with a package (requires OS X 10.8 or later). I haven't used this, and do not know if it will be able to remove MacFUSE and TrueCrypt.

Once you've done this, check the list of files/locations reported by Pacifist, see if any of those are still around and remove them.

Comment: +1 for UninstallPKG, such a great tool I've just met! :)

Answer (score 0):

Are you seeing a installation folder or an .exe file. Either way, the installation would not have gone anywhere, and I think it should safe to delete either. After you complete the delete, you can run a search for "TrueCrypt" to see if anything is left, but I doubt it would be.

However, I ran a check on [TrueCrypt](http://www.truecrypt.org) (truecrypt.org) and there is an OSX installer. If you have that, there may be more to be done. But you said you got a Windows installer, so I'll leave it at that.